# How to scrape website with content rendering from angular JS with python

Tags: python, angularjs, selenium, beautifulsoup

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xS5t5.jpg)I want to scrape content from website: https://www.fireant.vn/App#/company-data/ACB.

As far as i know, the content of tablea i want to scrape dynamically rendering data from Angularjs. They use ng-repeat to pass all value like time, volumn, price into the table.

```
</tr><!-- end ngRepeat: quote in intradayQuotes | orderBy: '-Date' --><tr ng-repeat="quote in intradayQuotes | orderBy: '-Date'" class="ng-scope">
```

This code from is as far as i can get as i really don't know what kind of object the table is

```
driver.get('https://www.fireant.vn/App#/company-data/ACB')
driver.set_window_position(0, 0)
driver.set_window_size(100000, 200000)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
```

Any instruction on the matter would be much helpful.

Data from table i want to get
[image: Data from table i want to get]

[print driver.page_source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1Sry.png)

Comment: Unfortunately your URL is not accessible without a log in, so it is quite difficult to test and debug code to answer this question.

Comment: Please check the screen shot from the link : i.stack.imgur.com/xS5t5.jpg. I really cannot sea any class available for me to return. Both price and time and type are at the same code structure?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to do some digging around on the site to find the CSS selectors (or xpath if you're more comfortable with xml) and use that to get the elements / text that you're interested in.

Instead of using beautiful soup, for Angular (and other Javascript rendered content) you can just grab the data right from webdriver.

for instance:

```
# driver.find_element_by_css_selector('<SELECTOR FOR THE ELEMENTS YOU WANT>')

prices = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('.price').text 
# Returns an array of text of all elements that have the .price class.
```

Comment: Please check the screen shot from the link : https://i.stack.imgur.com/xS5t5.jpg. I really cannot sea any class available for me to return. Both price and time and type are at the same code structure?

Answer (score 0):

Given the screenshot you posted, it seems that Price and Time have identical HTML element attributes -- however, you can use XPath indexing in this case to retrieve the item you want.

To retrieve price:

```
prices = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/b[@class='ng-binding']")
```

Based on the screenshot, it looks like the 'Price' text is in the 2nd `tr` element under `tbody`, and 'Price' cell is the 2nd `td` element under the `tr`. While I do not normally recommend this type of syntax, your scenario is a special case where the HTML is all nearly identical.